# How to Create a Character Countdown

Tags: php, jquery, countdown

I would like to know how to create a "Character Countdown". What I mean by this is that I have a **textarea** where you have to insert a minimum number of characters and I would like for that minimum to be a counter so when you start writing it will subtract each character to that minimum.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Edit: I have tried using PHP by counting the characters inside the *textarea* and using a *for* but I couldn't get these to update until afterwards of the post. I'm pretty much stuck on how to achieve this, sorry for not being able to give more information.

Comment: You need to put onKeyPress event on that textarea and work on it (or use Jquery)

Answer (score 1):

You need to bind a function to the change of the text field.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function () {
       $('#field_name').keyup(function () {
            //Change count here
       });
   });
</script>
```

Where I've commented, you can change the value of another element to contain the count of the length of the text box, for example:

```
$('#counter_element').val($('#field_name').val().length);
```

This will obviously need modifying to suit your needs, for example you will probably need an onsubmit() check to make sure the minimum characters has been reached.

Answer (score 0):

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/tjkD4/2/)**

Try This:

**HTML:**

```
<textarea id="smstemplate"></textarea>
<span id="remaining">0 characters</span>
```

**JS Code:**

```
$('#smstemplate').keyup(function () {
 var $remaining = $('#remaining'),
        $messages = $remaining.next();

            var chars = this.value.length; 
             messages = Math.ceil(chars / 160);


            $remaining.text((chars) + ' characters');

        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my take:

```
$('#myTextArea').keyup(function () {
    var lengthOfText;
    lengthOfText = $(this).val().length;

    if (lengthOfText < 15) {
        $('#myCounter').text(15 - lengthOfText);
        $('#myCounter').css("color", "red");
    } else {
        $('#myCounter').text("Minimum text written");
        $('#myCounter').css("color", "green");
    }
});
```

And the working fiddle: http://fiddle.jshell.net/Umv8k/